# It's possible to download only one Json with retrofit2 for time?

Tags: android, json, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm using this code to download a list of airports:

```
 final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(AirportService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT).build();


    AirportService service = retrofit.create(AirportService.class);

    service.getAirport()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Airport>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted()
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Airport> airports)
                {
                    airps = airports;
                }
            });
```

with this interface:

```
@GET("airports.json")
  Observable<List<Airport>> getAirport();
```

i want to know if it's possible to have in onNext() method Airport and not List . I'll try it but I've got error (because airports are about 40k) and if it's possible to add a progress bar to show the download.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Yes there are operators in rxjava that will help you acheive that. If its 40k can you not use pagination?

Comment: and if some reason you don't want to create restful web service, you can split the data into smaller files (for example: airport1.json, airport2.json) so you can access the data per page by using: `@GET("airport{page}.json") obvervable<List<Airport>> getAirport(@Query("page") page)`